# Sending a message to esp32 access point with javascript

Tags: javascript, sockets, esp32

The thing that I am trying to do is this:

1. Set an esp32 board as an access point.
2. Create a website where we can enter the credentials of the access point (ssid, pass), connect to it and then start exchanging messages with the board.

Now, after having set the esp32 as an access point, how can we connect to it with javascript and start exchaning messages ?

I am guessing I will have to use sockets, but I dont really know how to use them with javascript, and the information from the web for this topic is not really helpful for me.

Any guidance on how to achieve this or what to read would be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: The website is running on an orange pi board.

Comment: `connect to it with javascript` you can't connect to a wifi access point with javascript in a web page - the computer you're running the javascript on would need to connect to the access point

Comment: i am sorry, i forgot to mention it. I am running the website on an orange pi.

Comment: so? a web page can't control which access point the computer is connected to

Comment: That website would run in a browser, and the browser (fortunately) has no way to let websites to mess with wifi settings of the operating system. You can either have your ESP32 connect to the same existing access point as the Orange Pi, or you have to manually connect the client machine to the access point running on the ESP32 before accessing any service running on the ESP32.

Comment: @Thomas Ok, so now I have manually connected the client machine to the ESP32 access point. After that, how does the client sends messages to the esp32?

Comment: I'm not sure commands can be sent to the device over wifi. The [manual](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-at/en/latest/esp32/Get_Started/What_is_ESP-AT.html) says "By default, the host MCU connects to the ESP32 board via UART, and sends/receives AT commands/responses through UART. But you can also use other interfaces, such as SDIO, according to your actual use scenario." Do you know the way to configure it to use wifi to send commands? Is that even possible?

Comment: @MattEllen I have no idea. I was hoping to get some info here on how to start doing this.

Comment: you should serve the webpage from the esp32

Answer (score 0):

If your website is on an other device, the device should connect to the ESP32's AP. If this device on the esp's network, you can set up the routes on your ESP for posting credentials.

For example:

- ESP32 --> AP
- Device connects to ESP32's AP
- If connected, client can load webpages from the device on it's route.
- Device can POST a request to the ESP on a predefined route and save the things.

If your device is not connected to the esp's AP then it is not possible.

Another way is to setup a webpage on the ESP32 and serve everything from just the esp. In this case you can setup a server. For this i recommend this library: https://github.com/me-no-dev/ESPAsyncWebServer Everything is documented there.